# Stata Postfile Error: Invalid Name

Tags: stata

I am running into a strange problem while trying to run my code. The following is a sample of my code (Note: I am already in the main directory):

```
cd "C:/`mydir'" //where `mydir' is the local for the folder containing the fig folder.

use cleaned.dta, clear

local outcome drr_trtd 

tempname post_handle

local postfile_varlist str12(tau_text) double(pt_est se) 

postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' using "fig/dta/es_M12_P11_`outcome'.dta", replace

postclose `post_handle'

use "fig/dta/es_M12_P11_`outcome'.dta", clear
```

The issue is that whenever I try and run this code, I get an error:

```
postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' using "fig/dta/es_M12_P11_`outcome'.dta", replace
fig/dta/es_M12_P11_drr_trtd.dta invalid name
```

I assumed that this may be because of quotation marks, so I removed the quotation marks and then I get the following error:

```
postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' using fig/dta/es_M12_P11_`outcome'.dta, replace
/ invalid name
```

I then tried to make the file without a file-path that is I edited the postfile command as follows:

```
postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' using "hello.dta", replace
```

Now, with the quotations I get the error:

```
"hello.dta invalid name
```

Without the quotation I get the same error but with hello.dat. Am I just doing something obviously wrong here? I do not understand why I am getting this error.

New Code:

```
local mydir /Users/F H/Desktop/Ray/analysis
cd "C:/`mydir'/" 

tempname post_handle
local postfile_varlist str12(tau_text) double(pt_est se) 
pwd

postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' ///
    using "\fig\dta\event_study_M24_P59_sa.dta" ///
    , replace
```

I get the error:

```
(note: file \fig\dta\event_study_M24_P59_sa.dta not found)
file \fig\dta\event_study_M24_P59_sa.dta could not be opened
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I am already in the main directory". Does that mean you're in the `fig` directory? Try posting a reproducible example showing your error. Something like I've posted below. (I can't reproduce it.)

Comment: Are you using an updated version of Stata? Run `update`.

Comment: Are you running your code in parts? Run it all at once and report back.

Comment: Insert `macro list` just before the `postfile` call. That will show you which local macros are visible. The local macro `var` is not defined in your code, although that doesn't seem important here.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Hi, so I updated the code. I made some edits to make it a working code with all the settings I am using at the start of the file. This is the entire code at the moment and it is giving me an error. I do not know why.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for pointing out that typo. I have made the edits. "var" pretty much stands for "outcome". I have made the change. You are right, it is not important as I am still getting the rror after correcting for this mistake. Also, using `macro list' I find that all the defined macros are fine and are read by stata properly.

Comment: Stata would try to put the file in a subdirectory of your present directory. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't reproduce your error. Like I said before, try posting a reproducible example. That means someone can copy/paste your code in their own machines (with minimum changes) and be able to run it. Again, see my example below. Your error is with `postfile`, so you should maybe remove the rest of the code in your original question. It's distracting.

Comment: @NickCox So I want Stata to put the file in dta folder that is inside the fig folder that is inside mydir.

Comment: Do the `fig` and `dta` directories already exist?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer yes they do.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer So I just cleaned up the code as you requested. Should I make more changes? The error occurs even if I am not posting anything---the code is just like this on my machine but for some starting options.

Comment: What you want is one thing. Stata will interpret the filepath you give it as referring to something off your present working directory. Again, we can't discuss your code because you don't show your definition of the local `mydir`.

Comment: @NickCox ok so `mydir'= /Users/F H/Desktop/Ray/analysis

Comment: The blank in `F H` seems to be the problem. Why do you define a local with quotes? Is it not `local mydir ...`?

Comment: so local is defined as follows: local mydir /Users/F H/Desktop/Ray/analysis. When I call this local I need to put quotation marks because the space in F H is a problem.

Comment: That definition of `mydir` is not necessarily the problem. The question is whether `fig` is a subdirectory of `analysis`. You could just navigate to the directory where you want the file to be.

Comment: @NickCox it is. the fig folder lies inside the analysis folder.

Comment: Sorry, but I am out of ideas then.

Comment: Are you aware of the double `/`? Once when you define the `local mydir`, the other when doing `cd`. Could that be a problem in MS Windows?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Yeah I am aware of it. Stata auto corrects for it but I also double checked, just in case, and it doesnt make any difference. I guess I'll have to live with this error.

Comment: Have you run `pwd` to check that you are working where you should be?

Comment: @NickCox I just tried that and I am in the correct folder. i just added a `New Code` section to main post. When I run that I get the error: (note: file \fig\dta\event_study_M24_P59_sa.dta not found)
file \fig\dta\event_study_M24_P59_sa.dta could not be opened

Comment: In my system (Linux, Stata 12), I can reproduce such an error when the directory I'm trying to save to doesn't exist. In my example below, that means using something like `.../test3/...` and not `.../test2/...`

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Ok so this is beyond normal levels of confusing now. The commands do seem to work when executed in the command terminal of Stata. I have no clue that why these won't work when executed using a do file. Is stata just being dumb right now?

Comment: That's not an explanation at any level. I'm worried about this mention of a do-file. Where you did mention that before?  As before, please confirm that `macro list` shows up all locals as defined. It's not in your new code.

Comment: Okay. This code is being run from a do file. The do file lies in another subdirectory of the analysis folder (which shouldn't matter because I change the working directory to the correct analysis folder). Now, if I run the posted code, I get the errors mentioned above. After I get the error, if I simply run the postfile command, as it is written in the do file, in the command line of Stata, then it is creating the correct file in the correct folder.

Comment: As you have it coded, the do-file is not supposed to be in a subdirectory of `analysis`. It's supposed to be at the root of `analysis`, and there should be a subdirectory `fig/dta/` at the root of `analysis` also. This post is missing key information for its resolution a has now an immense amount of irrelevant information.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Okay so the subdirectories exist in the analysis folder. I just placed the do file in the analysis folder and I am still getting this error.

Comment: Yes, so I see that you `cd`, but I'm afraid I've run out of ideas too. It's difficult to follow your setup. Sorry.

Comment: I can't follow the details, but I still conjecture that Stata can't figure out where you want the output file compared with where you are working. I generally work in exactly the same directory as I want to save stuff. Naturally there are exceptions, but whereas I sometimes get confused, I have not known Stata to be wrong here.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for all the help. The thing is that I still get the error if i edit the postfile command to not include the fig/dta portion i.e. :`postfile 'post_handle' 'postfile_varlist' using es_M12_P11_'outcome'.dta, replace`, gives the same error. Shouldn't stata then simply create this file in the working directory (whatever it may be) and not give an error.

Comment: I've posted as a new answer (because it won't go in a comment readably) a test that worked for me when I have write permission in a directory and failed otherwise. Please try running that code in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test works for me so long as I have write permission in the current directory, and not otherwise.

```
sysuse auto, clear
local outcome drr_trtd 
tempname post_handle
local postfile_varlist str12(tau_text) double(my_price myrep)
postutil clear
postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' using `outcome'.dta, replace
post `post_handle' (make[1]) (price[1]) (rep78[1])
postclose `post_handle'
use `outcome'.dta, clear
list
```

Comment: Ok thanks. This works somehow. All I did was copy paste it in a new do file and adjusted it somewhat according to my own code. I still cannot get original do file to work but that is not a concern anymore because this outlay works with my code. You are my hero

Comment: @Roberto deserves quite as much praise as I do for jointly solving half your problem. We didn't identify the error you made. When you get enough reputation come back to give him a vote.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to reproduce your error. A working example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

local outcome drr_trtd 

tempname post_handle

local postfile_varlist str12(tau_text) double(my_price myrep)

postutil clear

postfile `post_handle' `postfile_varlist' ///
    using "test/test2/resu_lts_`outcome'.dta", replace

post `post_handle' (make[1]) (price[1]) (rep78[1])

postclose `post_handle'

use "test/test2/resu_lts_`outcome'.dta", clear

list
```

(I've created the appropriate testing directories.)